# Is there any way to validate EWS server URL programmatically?

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to programmatically validate the exchange server url (for e.g https://some-address/ews/exchange.asmx) programmatically. I have found ways where email credentials can be validated using ews. But I want to validate only URL, not using email credentials.

Any lead/help will be thankful :-)

Comment: The only sure way to validate is to actually hit that url with a request and handle the error (if one is returned).

Comment: Thanks! But I want to verify if the url is actually of exchange mail server and not any other url

Comment: See `X-ServerApplication` MIME header is present, e.g. `X-ServerApplication: Exchange/15.20.3045.014`